# Can you configure a single folder in a WordPress install that will allow directory list contents

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, configuration

I have a WordPress installation.  I would like to have one folder in the file structure where the url will show you the files and folders and allow you to browse and download from there.

Can it be done?

Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a separate .htaccess file for the directory you want to be viewable.  Be careful that directories deeper than the one you are in as .htaccess works downstream/cascades.

More info via: [http://www.wise-women.org/tutorials/htaccess/](https://web.archive.org/web/20081224233707/http://www.wise-women.org/tutorials/htaccess/)

**Allow directory browsing**

There may be times when you want or need to allow visitors to browse a directory. For example, you may need to allow access to files in a directory for downloading purposes on a server that is configured to not allow it.

Many servers are configured so that visitors cannot browse directories. In that case visitors will not see the contents of the directory but will instead get an error message.

You can override the servers settings and allow directory browsing with this line:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropriate `Location` or `Directory` section and put inside it:

```
Options +Indexes
```